# How to get notified when $.getJSON that calls $.getJSON all is all done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say I have the following javascript:

```
(function($) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.rows, function(index, row) {
      $.getJSON(url2, function(data2) {
        //Do something with data2, like adding it to an element on the page.
        //When all rows have been processed, by this function, I want to
        //call a function.
      }
    }
  }
})(jQuery)
```

I would like to be notified when all the inner $.getJSON has returned.

In my real code, I will use a callback function that I would like to be called when all requests are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) for this, like:

```
(function($) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

    $.when.apply($, $(data.rows).map(function (idx, row) {
      // return deferred object
      return $.getJSON(url, function () {
        // single callback
        console.log('one done');
      });
    }))
    .then(function () {
      // success callback
      console.log('success');
    }, function () {
      // failure callback
      console.log('failure');
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

**Edit**: just realised that `when` won't taken an array as argument, so I changed the code use `.apply` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You know how many of the 2nd getJSON's you are performing, because it is based on the size of the data you got from the first.  So keep track of how many times the 2nd getJSON has executed, and when it matches the size of the original data, you're done.

```
(function($) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var count = 0;
    $.each(data.rows, function(index, row) {
      $.getJSON(url2, function(data2) {
         count++;
         if(count === data.rows.length){
             console.log('all done!');
         } 
      }
    }
  }
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for jQuery's [when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and [then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) functions.

Example usage:

```
var firstGet = $.getJSON(...),
    secondGet = $.getJSON(...);

$.when(firstGet(), secondGet())
.then(
    function (data1, data2) { alert('success!'); },
    function () { alert('fail'); }
);
```

Comment: with this pattern, we have to know how many "inner getJSON" we need (one variable for each one), which he doesn't know at "coding time"

Comment: what do you mean? just use the length of the data.rows that is returned by the first getJSON

Answer (score 0):

Both answer are good. I would just notice that this pattern is not that good, because let's imagine your first call (`$.getJSON(url)`) return 50 elements (not that big), you'll then make **50 AJAX requests** quite simultaneously, which is very high ! It may slow down the browser and create an overhead for the server.
Maybe, the first call could return all the data you need ? Then your problem is solved, your server is safe and your users are happiest.